# CREATE TABLE AS SELECT returns error 'Failed to open HDFS file for writing'

Tags: sql, hdfs, cloudera, create-table, impala

I created a Cloudera cluster for Impala.

- Cloudera version: Cloudera Express 5.8.1
- Impala version: 2.6.0-cdh5.8.0 RELEASE

If I run the following command via `impala-shell`:

```
create table test as select 1;
```

The following error is returned:

```
WARNINGS: Failed to open HDFS file for writing: hdfs://[DNhostname]:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test/_impala_insert_staging/[...]/[...].0.
Error(255): Unknown error 255
```

However, if I run:

```
create table test (testcol int);
insert into test select 1;
```

...The table is created without a hitch.

Any ideas on why the first statement might fail while the second set of commands would succeed, and what I could do to fix it? I might have messed something up with directory permissions, either locally or on HDFS, however I've set `dfs.permissions` to false to turn off HDFS permissions. I don't know what to check on the local folders to ensure the correct user(s) have the right permissions. In either case, I don't know why the permissions would cause the `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` statement to fail but not `CREATE`, then `INSERT`.

I should also mention that `DNhostname` is the hostname of the HDFS datanode/impala daemon that I'm SSHed into, not the hostname of the namenode.  This worries me because `DNhostname` was originally where my namenode was located; I moved it to a different host for reasons outside the scope of this question.  Is it possible that `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` is still expecting the namenode to be `DNhostname` for some reason?

Comment: you don't typically perform an insert with CREATE TABLE syntax

Comment: @TMcKeown it is possible in Impala: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_create_table.html

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new table with the default DB path since you are not specifying a new path in your create statement. If you try to use another DB for this process, you most likely to be successful.

```
create database newdb
use newdb
create table test as select 1
```

This will prove the location of this DB is wrong in the metastore. Go to your metastore.dbs and find the ID of your database there. You need to set the location of your db correctly, like:

```
update <metastoreDB>.DBS set LOCATION = 'hdfs://NN_URI:8020/user/hive/warehouse' where id = id_of_your_db;'
```